# How to keep fragment names in Firebase Analytics with Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, firebase-analytics

I am using default Firebase Analytics implementation described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android

But when I check results in Firebase, name of fragments are "g,d,e,b". How can I fix this without hardcoding fragment names?

Comment: You need to instruct proguard to keep certain classes name. So if your fragments are in a certain package/folder com.example.app.fragments, you can use `-keepnames class com.example.app.fragments.*`. If this is what you want, let me know to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Abkarino are you sure about this? I tried it, made build and analyze it and it seems to be still obfuscated. I also do not understand, why activites are normal, but fragments are not.

Comment: this is the way, I would say you download Jadx and open your apk, if you see the fragments with their original names then it should work, else you did something wrong.

Comment: Can you share the full path of the fragments and the edited line you used in your proguards file?

Comment: @Abkarino Ok, I got it, I have to make full path, like "com.example.fragments.*" 
Thank you.

Comment: So, does this solve your question?

Comment: @Abkarino Yes, with small modification. Because your way I would have to add paths to all packages, where fragments are.

Comment: Why post your answer, I was waiting for you to confirm so I would make it as an answer myself :(

Answer (score 1):

To keep the fragment names when using ProGuards, you should use `-keepnames`.

Lets assume  you have a fragment with class identifier

```
com.example.app.fragments.frag1
```

To exclude that frag, you should add

```
-keepnames com.example.app.fragments.frag1 {}
```

To exclude all fragments including those that are in subfolders, use

```
-keepnames com.example.app.fragments.** {}
```

`-keepnames` is short for `-keep,allowshrinking`. If you use `-keep` only, you lose all ProGuards optimizations.

If you want properties to maintain their name, use

```
-keepnames com.example.app.fragments.** {*;}
```

For more information, you can check [this.](https://jebware.com/blog/?p=418)

Answer (score -1):

Based on answer from @Abkarino, I came up with follwing solution:

```
-keep class com.packagename.fragments** { *; }
```

Where "com.packagename.fragments" is path to root of all fragments in project.